# Linux: Using user accounts to ensure process separation and safety

Tags: linux, security

I'm tasked with writing a service where several externally provided programs/daemons will be executing on the same machine. The problem I'm facing is that while these daemons *should* be well behaved and not be malicious, there is no guarantee that this will always be the case and I'd prefer to be paranoid from the start rather than sorry later.

As such, I'm looking for a method which prevents these daemons from reading each other's data files (which may contain sensitive information). After doing some thinking, I am thinking that it would be sufficient to

```
1) Create a separate user for each daemon
2) Create these users with each user having their own group
3) Set directory permissions for each home directory to 700
4) Execute each daemon from it's own user account
```

Does anybody see anything blatantly wrong with this? I'm assuming that the standard process/memory separation built into Linux will take care of protecting each daemon's memory at runtime so the only danger would seem to be daemons reading each others data files.

Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Souns like the android way, also you might interested in reading this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/292925/how-to-sandbox-applications

Comment: Thanks for the link, lots of good info there ...